# Need help to clarify understanding example of time nature from Hawking's book "Briefer History of Time"

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, time, education

I'm reading Hawking's book "Briefer History of Time" both in Ukrainian and Russian languages and found a possible translation mistake in this paragraph (last page of "Chapter 6. CURVED SPACE"):

> This prediction was tested in 1962, using a pair of very accurate
> clocks mounted at the top and bottom of a water tower. The clock at
> the bottom, which was nearer the earth, was found to run slower, in
> exact agreement with general relativity. The effect is a small one-a
> clock on the surface of the sun would **gain** only about a minute a year
> as compared to one on the surface of the earth. Yet with the advent of
> very accurate navigation systems based on signals from satellites, the
> difference in the speed of clocks at different heights above the earth
> is now of considerable practical importance. If you ignored the
> predictions of general relativity, the position that you calculated
> would be wrong by several miles!

In Russian translation:

> Данное предсказание было проверено в 1962 г. с помощью пары очень
> точных часов, установленных на вершине и у подножия водонапорной
> башни. Часы у основания, которые были ближе к Земле, шли медленнее в
> точном соответствии с общей теорией относительности. Этот эффект очень
> мал: часы, размещенные на поверхности Солнца, лишь на минуту в год
> **обгоняли** бы такие же часы, находящиеся на Земле. Однако с появлением
> сверхточных навигационных систем, получающих сигналы от спутников,
> разность хода часов на различных высотах приобрела практическое
> значение. Если бы аппаратура игнорировала предсказания общей теории
> относительности, ошибка в определении местоположения могла бы
> достигать нескольких километров!

As I see, time is passing slower in the more massive object, so the clock near the Sun should go slower than near the Earth - because the Earth has less weight.

So, in the sentence:

> The effect is a small one-a clock on the surface of the sun would **gain(=late)** only about a minute a year as compared to one on the surface of the earth.

the word `gain` could be replaced by `late`, am I right?

And the Russian translation should be corrected:

> Published translation:
> Этот эффект очень мал: часы, размещенные на поверхности Солнца, лишь на минуту в год **обгоняли** бы такие же часы, находящиеся на Земле.
>
> =>
>
> Corrected translation:
> Этот эффект очень мал: часы, размещенные на поверхности Солнца, лишь на минуту в год **отставали** бы от таких же часов, находящихся на Земле.

Because, in the currently published translation, it means: "clock near the Sun goes faster relative to the Earth's clock" - that is wrong according to relativity theory.

So, my question is: the word `gain` could be replaced by `late` in the original text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The use of the word `gain' here means that after 1 year has elapsed on the sun-clock, 1 year and one minute will have elapsed on the earth-clock. As I understand it, outrun is more correct than lag. Lag (or being late) would imply that a clock shows more time has passed, which is exactly opposite to the effect here. Outrun seems to imply that the clock reaches a set time interval (here, 1 year) faster/sooner in comparison to the other clock, which is correct. However, I do not speak Russian, so I am going off your definitions and translations here.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just a bit clarified the question: 
the word 'gain' could be replaced by 'late' in the original text?